# What does double asterisk mean in vue router path?

Tags: vue-router

I have seen some vue router configuration included this patter in path like:

```
{path: "**", component: Xxx}
```

What does this mean and what is difference compared with `path: "*"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand `"*"` and `"**"` should have the same functionality since `*` should match **anything**. The only difference between `"*"` and `"**"` that I can deduce from the source code relates to [this](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/dist/vue-router.js#L1125) part of the code:

```
// ensure wildcard routes are always at the end
for (var i = 0, l = pathList.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (pathList[i] === '*') {
       pathList.push(pathList.splice(i, 1)[0]);
```

This code block would move `"*"` routes to the end which means that all other routes that have been defined would be matched first before the wildcard route gets matched. However, `"**"` would not be moved to the end which means that any routes defined after `"**"` would not be matched.

Comment: Thank you! Now it makes sense to me.